# Why is the comparator used instead of the equals() in Collections?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

There is a java bean Car that might contains two values: model and price.

Now suppose I override equals() and hashcode() checking only for model in that way:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {            
    return this.model.equals(o.model);
}


public int hashCode() {
    return model.hashCode();
}
```

This permit me to check if an arraylist already contain an item Car of the same model (and doesn't matter the price), in that way:

```
List<Car> car = new ArrayList<Car>();


car.add(new Car("carA",100f));
car.add(new Car("carB",101f));
car.add(new Car("carC",110f));

System.out.println(a.contains(new Car("carB",111f)));
```

It returns TRUE. That's fine, because the car already exist!

But now I decide that the ArrayList is not good, because I want to maintain the items ordered, so I substitute it with a TreeSet in this way:

```
Set<Car> car = new TreeSet<Car>(new Comparator<Car>() {
@Override 
public int compare(Car car1, Car car2) {

    int compPrice = - Float.compare(car1.getPrice(), car2.getPrice());

    if (compPrice > 0 || compPrice < 0)
        return compPrice;
    else
        return car1.getModel().compareTo(car2.getModel());
```

}});

```
car.add(new Car("carA",100f));
car.add(new Car("carB",101f));
car.add(new Car("carC",110f));

System.out.println(a.contains(new Car("carB",111f)));
```

But now there is a problem, it return FALSE... why?

It seems that when I invoke contains() using an arrayList the method equals() is invoked.
But it seems that when I invoke contains() using a TreeSet with a comparator, the comparator is used instead.

Why does that happen?

Comment: From TreeSet javadoc, I think it says it all: "Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) *must be consistent with equals* if it is to correctly implement the Set interface." link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Comment: A `TreeSet` probably isn't the right data structure here.

Answer (score 3):

A `TreeSet` is implicitly sorted, and it uses a `Comparator` for this sorting.  The `equals()` method can only tell you if two objects are the same or different, not how they should be ordered for sorting.  Only a `Comparator` can do that.

More to the point, a `TreeSet` also uses comparisons for **searching**.  This is sort of the whole point of tree-based map/set.  When the `contains()` method is called, a binary search is performed and the target is either found or not found, based on how the comparator is defined.  The comparator defines not only logical order but also logical identity.  If you are relying on logical identity defined by an inconsistent `equals()` implementation, then confusion will probably ensue.

Answer (score 3):

`TreeSet` forms a binary tree keeping elements according to natural (or not) orders, so in order to search quickly one specific element is the collection, `TreeSet` uses `Comparable` or `Comparator` instead of `equals()`.

As [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) JavaDoc precises:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator
>   for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so
>   because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation,
>   but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its
>   compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal
>   by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The
>   behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent
>   with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set
>   interface.

We can find a similarity with the HashCode/Equals contract:

*If `equals()` returns `true`, `hashcode()` **has to** return true too in order to be found during search.*

Likewise with `TreeSet`:

*If `contains()` (using `Comparator` or `Comparable`) returns `true`, `equals()` **has to** return `true` too in order to be **consistent** with `equals()`.*

**THEREFORE:** Fields used within `TreeSet.equals()` method have to be exactly the same (no more, no less) than within your `Comparator` implementation.

Comment: Although I tried to answer this question myself, and I do understand that in principle a binary search must make comparisons as it navigates the tree, I share some of the OP's confusion.  Specifically, the Javadoc states that `equals()` is used by `contains()`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29   Where is the "contract" you describe documented?

Comment: @The111 I wrote that since it seems perfectly logic. However, I agree that Javadoc doesn't precise it. I guessJavadoc explains mechanism quite briefly using the conceptual algorithm `o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)` without entering into real implementations details.

Comment: @The111 In fact, the weird sentence relative to usage of `equals()`simply refers to the `Set` interface's `contains()` Javadoc.

Comment: So, if an equals() that works only on "model" is needed, follows that ArrayList should be used instead of TreeSet, is it right? Because there is no conflict with any comparator in this case: I can just pass the comparetor I want to Collections.sort() and in this case it's not part of the list.

Comment: @user1883212 As long as you define `compareTo()` and `equals()` method differently, you cannot guarantee the perfect consistence of `TreeSet` behavior. If you really can't alter these methods (which is pretty bad...), so yes, `ArrayList` would be preferred, or even better `HashSet`.

Comment: @user1883212 Yes, `Collection.sort()` could do the trick. So, you can rather use `HashSet` instance.

Comment: @user1883212 You'll just lose in term of performance since `Collection.sort` generates a complexity of O(n log(n)) whereas `TreeSet` generates one of O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the different behaviour is, that you consider the price member in the compare method, but ignore it in equals.

```
new Car("carB",101f)     // what you add to the list   
new Car("carB",111f)     // what you are looking for
```

Both instances are "equals" (sorry...) since their model members are equal (and the implementation stops after that test). They "compare" as different, though, because *that* implementation also checks the price member.

Comment: Yes, equals() and compare() work on different values in the bean. But the call contains() is always the same, altought returning different results.